# Property of $n$th derivative of a real-valued function

Tags: functions, derivatives

$Q)$ Let $f(x)$ be a real valued function of a real variable, such that $\ |f^{(n)}(0)|\leq K$   for all $ n\in N$, where $K\gt0$. Then state and explain whether the following statement is true
$$ "f^{(n)}(x) \ exists\ for\ all\ x\in R\ and\ for\ all\ n\in N" $$
$A)$ I think it is false and here is my explanation.

Since the function $\ f(x)$ is not specified, I assume the above statement is true only when it is true for all such functions $\ f(x)$ which satisfy the condition mentioned in the question. So I am going to prove the statement wrong by giving an example of one such function which satisfies the condition but for which the above mentioned statement is false.
Let $$ f(x)=\begin{cases}
e^x, & x\in[-1,1]\\ [x], & x\notin[-1,1]
\end{cases}$$ 
as we can calculate $\ f^{(n)}(0)=1$ for all $n\in N$ so it satisfies the condition $\ |f^{(n)}(0)|\leq K$   for all $ n\in N$, where $K\gt0$ since here $K$ can be equal to $2$. But as we know $[x]$ which represents the greatest integer function is not differentiable everywhere. So the statement is false for the above function.

This question was asked in a very recent exam I wrote. I thought the answer was "false" but the answer key states "true". This is not supposed to be the final answer key as the students can still challenge the answer key. So which one do you think is correct. If you think I am correct and the answer is "false" can you provide me a better proof so that I can challenge the answer key.

And if you think I am wrong and the answer is "true". Please explain why. Do you think it is because the statement and condition are satisfied for some function $f(x)$ if not for all ?

Comment: The key answer is  certainly not correct. What you have done is fine and it is more than enough to challenge the key answer.